# Zend Framework - long routes(Router)

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I'm already thinking about to start using simple GET string.

Or I'm not so good at configuring routes? :)

And configuring routes via regex in .htaccess

```
foreach($links as $a) 
{

$Router->addRoute($a['link'],
                  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                      $a['link'] . '/:page/:ad_id/:photo/:price_from/:price_to/:regions/:rajoni/:towns/:pagasti/:gadi_from/:gadi_to/:augums_from/:augums_to',
                      array
                      ("page" => 1,
        "ad_id" => 0,
        "photo" => 0,
        "price_from" => 0,
        "price_to" => 0,
        "regions" => 'def',
        "rajoni" => 'def',
        "towns" => 'def',
        "pagasti" => 'def',
        "gadi_from" => 'def',
        "gadi_to" => 'def',
        "augums_from" => 'def',
        "augums_to" => 'def',
        "department" => $a['department'],
        "category" => '',
        "link" => $a['link'],
        "controller" => "ads",
                       "action"     => "view",
                      ))); 
}
```

Please help me to find a right way to use Zend Framework Routes

After edit:

By the way, is it ok to loop through categories to bind route to them?
So urls could be human readable?

Or better to stick to .htaccess file configuration? But I still didn't figured out, how to make human readable urls without adding number for categories to regex.

```
  RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L]
  RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2 [L]
```

The only way I have figured out, is to pass actual name of category as value and on server side compare it with array of category names.

Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this route to show results of a search? If that's the case, I would strongly recommend avoiding routes of this length - they're harder to maintain (try adding another parameter) - use a GET query string as normal.

Structure something like /ads/view/:page/?ad_id=xxx&...

Comment: Yea i'm about to stick to it.